# I am getting an error in the ansible playbook

Tags: ansible-playbook

I am trying to learn ansible and I have coded my first playbook but it gives me the error saying

> ERROR! A playbook must be a list of plays, got a <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleMapping'> instead
>
> The error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/playbook/ngix.yml': line 1, column 1, but may
> be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
>
> The offending line appears to be:
>
> ```
>   name: Ping all servers
>   ^ here
> ```

I am trying to ping all servers below is the file

```yaml
name: Ping all servers
hosts: prod
become: yes

task:
ping
```

Can someone please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Your playbook should look like this:

```yaml
---

- name: Ping all servers
  hosts: prod
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - ping:
```

Comment: Still don't work gives the below error ------------------(myansible) [root@Master playbook]# ./doc.yml 
./doc.yml: line 1: ---: command not found
./doc.yml: line 3: -: command not found
./doc.yml: line 4: hosts:: command not found
./doc.yml: line 5: become:: command not found
./doc.yml: line 6: tasks:: command not found
./doc.yml: line 7: -: command not found
(myansible) [root@Master playbook]# -------------

Comment: Are you trying to execute a .yml file as a script file?